# Cache (tag/set/offset ) easy

Tags: caching

Eight way sets associative ache memory has a total of 512 slots; each block has 128 bytes, find the format for  addression if main memory is 256k bytes.

Tag 
set 
offset

I've got 9 for the set
7 for the offset,

i've forgotten how to figure out what the tag is >.< i tried googling

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. 
As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: what is the tag, the set, and the offset for this problem^.